# elasticsearch alias with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

I am using rails with elasticsearch, thanks to the elasticsearch-rails gem ( https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-persistence )

I am using the repository model as described in the documentation, I can change the index, but is it possible to use the alias feature of ES? If so, how?
Example:

```
require 'elasticsearch/persistence'
repository = Elasticsearch::Persistence::Repository.new
repository.index = "myindex"
```

works fine, but no indication on how to create an alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new 
# or other es client
client.indices.update_aliases body: {
  actions: [
    { add: { index: 'your_index_name', alias: 'your_alias_name' } }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update alias without downtime

```
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new 
# or other es client
client.indices.update_aliases body: {
  actions: [
{ remove: { index: 'your_old_index_name', alias: 'your_alias_name' } },
{ add: { index: 'your_new_index_name', alias: 'your_alias_name' } }
]
}
```